# Style table borders to not move on row highlight?

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a dropdown menu using a table. I am adding the jQueryUI-provided "ui-state-highlight" class for row highlighting.

My issue is that right now, **whenever an item is highlighted it makes the size of the menu change by a few pixels**. I've tried to fix this issue using padding but it doesn't seem to work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayAy4/3/)

To be more general, **how do you style an element to maintain the same width/height when a child element is resized without explicitly setting the height and width?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that shake effect is because of the border 1px. The border was added when you mouseenter and removed when mouseleave which is causing that effect.

You can avoid it by a cheap trick,

```
 //Change white if the background color of your screen is different.
 tr { border: 1px solid white; }
```

**Edit**: You can use transparent color to avoid matching with what background color is.

```
tr { border: 1px solid transparent; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/ayAy4/8/) here

Comment: This is a cool trick, but as you pointed out it's kind of cheap. Additionally, the site I'm working on uses jQuery themeroller, so the user has the option of changing the style at any time so the background is subject to change. Is it possible to set an invisible border? Or should I be modifying the parent's padding or something upon row hover?

Comment: Yes, you can use transparent color 'tr { border: 1px solid transparent; }'.

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

Add a new style to the TR element, an "invisible" border that matches the background of the container. Then on hover, it's not adding to the height, instead the border-color is just changing.

`tr {
    border:#fff solid 1px;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/ayAy4/11/

Comment: Looks like someone else just posted the same answer as I updated mine.